# What is wrong in this reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, heterocyclic-compounds, grignard-reagent

> What is wrong in this reaction?
>
> [image: Reaction scheme]

I cannot find anything wrong, please help. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: The acidic hydrolysis would prolly be interfered by the presence of the basic nitrogen on the ring

Comment: More than that, Grignard reagents are also strong bases. The proton from the NH would quench any Grignard that formed. You need to protect the NH.

Comment: @YUSUFHASAN Actually it's like only thing that would work. Even the substrate could react with itself!

Comment: @Mithoron Won't the H+ be wasted in reacting with the N of the substrate?

Comment: @YUSUFHASAN It's quenching of alkoxide - last step, you'd need to use different method to make it in the first place, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the free $\ce{NH}$. Grignard reagents are strong bases ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}\sim 50$), strong enough to deprotonate $\ce{R2NH}$. Any Grignard that formed would be immediately quenched by the free $\ce{NH}$. You need to protect, this is typically done with *t*BOC, more discussion [here](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2015/11/13/organometallics-are-strong-bases/).

Comment: This seems weird to me..I mean, I assumed that once the Grignard reagent starts forming,would it abstract a proton from another Grignard molecule, considering repulsion b/w two negatively charged species?

Comment: the quench is most likely internal. So the net reaction is reduction of the secondary bromide to methylene